# npm install wipes out any linked modules

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-link

Say I `npm link` `moduleA`, and then in `projectB` I run `npm link moduleA`, then I wind up with a symlink to `moduleA` in `projectB/node_modules/moduleA`.

However, if I run `npm install` in `projectB`, then `moduleA` is now missing from `projectB/node_modules` and I have to run `npm link moduleA` again.

Its there a way to persist `npm link`'d modules between `npm install`s?